# MySQL Container keep not connecting to my container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm starting `mysql` server using `docker-compose` here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysqlcontainer
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0_init.sql
      - C:/Users/crisp/OneDrive/Desktop/html/database:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:3306
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: todos
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysqldb
    networks:
      - internalnet
networks:
  internalnet:
    driver: bridge
```

Now when i use the `ps` docker command here is what i'm getting. The status is always `Restarting`

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                        PORTS     NAMES
6f8053143edf   mysql:8.0   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 seconds ago   Restarting (1) 1 second ago             mysqlcontainer
```

If i try to debug using the `logs` command on the container here are the logs I'm getting

```bash
2022-08-03 06:13:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:13:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:13:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:13:32.094297Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:13:32.108996Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:13:32.109026Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:13:32.122288Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:13:32.235605Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:13:32.929506Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:13:33.170552Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:13:33.170867Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:13:33.171051Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:13:33.172827Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:13:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:13:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:13:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:13:37.902864Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:13:37.916272Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:13:37.916302Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:13:37.929765Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:13:37.974966Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:13:38.676248Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:13:38.959483Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:13:38.959809Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:13:38.959870Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:13:38.961245Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:13:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:13:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:13:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:13:43.811176Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:13:43.826556Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:13:43.826611Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:13:43.846354Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:13:43.918855Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:13:44.772517Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:13:45.021113Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:13:45.021339Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:13:45.021415Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:13:45.023388Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:13:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:13:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:13:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:13:49.826617Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:13:49.839972Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:13:49.840130Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:13:49.854179Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:13:49.907502Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:13:50.701530Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:13:50.932839Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:13:50.933362Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:13:50.933448Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:13:50.934985Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:13:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:13:55+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:13:55+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:13:55.672533Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:13:55.686526Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:13:55.686557Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:13:55.700405Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:13:55.796139Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:13:56.593853Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:13:56.867322Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:13:56.867705Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:13:56.867752Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:13:56.869591Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:14:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:14:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:14:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:14:01.815025Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:14:01.827254Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:14:01.827284Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:14:01.838250Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:14:01.929735Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:14:02.836305Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:14:03.051822Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:14:03.052113Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:14:03.052150Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:14:03.053717Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:14:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:14:09+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:14:09+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:14:09.708213Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:14:09.718157Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:14:09.718187Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:14:09.728521Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:14:09.785854Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:14:10.556984Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:14:10.847891Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:14:10.848129Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:14:10.848165Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:14:10.849647Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:14:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:14:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:14:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:14:20.807168Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:14:20.819200Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:14:20.819231Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:14:20.829042Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:14:20.904475Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:14:21.745379Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:14:22.019620Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:14:22.020038Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:14:22.020116Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:14:22.021569Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:14:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:14:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:14:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:14:38.336495Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:14:38.346879Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:14:38.346910Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:14:38.355982Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:14:38.401038Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:14:39.439981Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:14:39.688466Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:14:39.688836Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:14:39.688881Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:14:39.690256Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:15:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:15:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:15:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:15:08.812491Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:15:08.824051Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:15:08.824083Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:15:08.835330Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:15:08.884074Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:15:09.598467Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:15:09.842765Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:15:09.843038Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:15:09.843109Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:15:09.844406Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:16:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:16:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:16:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:16:05.411826Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:16:05.422864Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:16:05.422895Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:16:05.437596Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:16:05.486536Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:16:06.235782Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:16:06.504590Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:16:06.504893Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:16:06.504965Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:16:06.506629Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:17:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:17:09+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:17:09+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:17:09.710388Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:17:09.725995Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:17:09.726036Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:17:09.738785Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:17:09.836029Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:17:10.640444Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:17:10.933443Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:17:10.933749Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:17:10.933812Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:17:10.935379Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:18:13+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:18:13+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:18:13+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:18:14.339873Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:18:14.355514Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:18:14.355556Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:18:14.367405Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2022-08-03T06:18:14.470999Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:18:15.216762Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:18:15.409546Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:18:15.409939Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:18:15.409979Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:18:15.412445Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:19:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:19:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:19:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:19:18.568091Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:19:18.582955Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:19:18.582987Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:19:18.596502Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:19:18.689140Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:19:19.579966Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:19:19.845619Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:19:19.845948Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:19:19.846001Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:19:19.847771Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:20:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:20:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:20:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:20:23.335838Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:20:23.346428Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:20:23.346459Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:20:23.358021Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:20:23.442383Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:20:24.334394Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:20:24.581742Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:20:24.582067Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:20:24.582145Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:20:24.583429Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-03 06:21:26+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-03 06:21:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-03 06:21:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-03T06:21:27.858128Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-03T06:21:27.871861Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-03T06:21:27.871891Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-03T06:21:27.886573Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive    
2022-08-03T06:21:27.937394Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-03T06:21:28.781122Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-08-03T06:21:29.056997Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-03T06:21:29.057329Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-03T06:21:29.057392Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-03T06:21:29.058769Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I don't know if these logs makes sense, but i can see that at the last line it says `Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.`.

When i try to connect to this mysql server on docker, here is the error that i'm getting.

```bash
"There was an error processing your request: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080"
```

Probably I'm missing something small here, what maybe possibly the cause of this.

Comment: This probably has something to do with the connection port. "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080", based on the base image the MySQL service starts on port 3306 on which the service INSIDE container still listens. With your port mapping to 8080 you actually only map the "outside" communication to the internal port of 3306. NOTE: docker internal networks communication work with internal ports not published ones.

Comment: @matic1123 Yes the reason i'm mapping to 8080 it's because i want it to connect to nodejs extenally. I believe the error is here `Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL..`  my sql stutdown for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the data folder was corrupt during the first installation or upgradation in the middle of the building or not properly closed.

**Try this step**.

Try to remove the docker image.
List all images using

```
docker images
```

Remove the MySQL image

```
docker rmi imagename
```

**Update: Don't forget to remove the docker volume**

Find the Volumes

```
docker volume ls
```

Remove the volume

```
docker volume rm volumename
```

Also, go to your directory `C:/Users/crisp/OneDrive/Desktop/html/database` and remove the folder.

**For Remove unused container use**

```
docker system prune -a
```

Then try `docker-compose up` for debugging.
If no errors, you could try `docker-compose up -d`.

Comment: thanks for your contribution, it seems not working as well the status is `Restarting (1) 6 seconds ago` when i run the `ps` command.

Comment: `docker volume ls`, finding the problematic volume, and `docker volume rm volumename` resolved it for me.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error in your output is:

> 2022-08-03T06:21:28.781122Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.

Don't mount a Windows folder into the Linux container for a mysql data store:

```
volumes:
  - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0_init.sql
  - C:/Users/crisp/OneDrive/Desktop/html/database:/var/lib/mysql
```

Use a named volume so the file system is local to the VM running Docker

```
    volumes:
      - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0_init.sql
      - todo_db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  todo_db: {}
```

When you do this the database will go back to an initial blank state. Restore the database from a backup if there was something important in there.

Comment: Now i'm getting another error, saying `There was an error processing your request: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.` Isn't it that when you run the command `docker-compose up -d` you get the id back? Right now i'm not getting an id it just tell me that the container was created.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little old but I had the same issue in app-containers and azure file shares using bicep the fix was just too add mountOptions

```
      {
      // this is where grafana will persist its config
      name: 'grafana-storage'
      storageName: 'grafana-storage'
      storageType: 'AzureFile'
      mountOptions: 'uid=1000,gid=1000,nobrl,mfsymlinks,cache=none' // this too long to work out :)
    }
```