# Mongo DB docker container Authentication Issue

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose

I am recently facing a weird problem regarding mongod container. I have a server machine whose IP address is 17.17.17.17. In that machine I am trying to deploy my Mongo DB, and I want it to be accessible from other machines. I have used the following command to deploy mongo db and allowed the port 27017 in the firewall.

```
docker run -d \
   --name mongo \
   -p 27017:27017 \
   -v /path/to/mongo:/data/db \
   -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root \
   -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
   mongo:latest
```

The mongo db container is running but when I try to access it from other machine either via mongosh or via a nodejs process (mongoose library) it is not accessible.

I am using the following command to access mongodb deployed in this machine from other machine:

```
mongosh --host 17.17.17.17. --port 27017 --username root --password password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

This shows authentication error everytime and in the server machine logs, it says it is not getting any user named root in the admin database.

In the nodejs , I am using the following urls to connect to the mongodb:

```
mongodb://root:password@17.17.17.1:27017/test?authSource=admin
mongodb://root:password@17.17.17.1:27017/admin?authSource=admin
```

Again, it fails to connect to the mongodb.

However, if I do not use any kind of authentication to deploy mongo db, it can be accessed both via mongoose and nodejs.

For example if I use this:

```
docker run -d \
   --name mongo \
   -p 27017:27017 \
   -v /path/to/mongo:/data/db \
 mongo:latest
```

It is accessible both via mongosh and nodejs library from other machines.

Can anyone tell me what is the main problem here?

Comment: Any feedback?  If any of the answers below solved your problem remember [to accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 0):

The [image description](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) on Docker Hub says that `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWOR` have no effect

> if you start the container with a data directory that already contains
> a database: any pre-existing database will always be left untouched on
> container startup.

Since you are using a persistent volume, I guess that you runned Mongo for the first time without authentication and then you restarted Mongo with  authentication enabled but using the same volume.  Just retry with a new volume.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't use persistent volume like that. Instead, you should use `volumes` with `docker-compose`. Because [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73218293/16142058) it is explained, you will face a lot of problems: permission,... or like @Pino' answer

You can reference my config with docker-compose. You just create a simple `docker-compose.yml` file and run `docker-compose up -d`. And `docker-compose down` stop and remove containers.

Default, the only things removed are

- Containers for services defined in the Compose file
- Networks defined in the networks section of the Compose file
- The default network, if one is used

Networks and volumes defined as external are never removed.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  spring-mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: spring-mongodb
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - spring-mongodb-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - spring_mongodb_network
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo 10.10.10.60:27017/test --quiet
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  spring-mongodb-data:
    name: mongodb-data

networks:
  spring_mongodb_network:
    name: spring_mongodb_network
```

After, you can interact with Mongo DB by mongosh or Mongo Compass GUI

You can read more about `volumes` to understand docker manages volume. Volumes was stored at `\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes` in my windows machine

[image]

Comment: @jaintapaul, if it resolve your problem or useful for you, please upvote or accept it.